# Not able to integrate AspectJ with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, aspectj

I banged my head for two days to integrate aspectj with maven, But did not work. 
I am writing a simple program with two advices (which works fine in eclipse, so I am sure it's not a code side error).

I have recently started using maven for project building. Can't think of why I am not able to kick off aspectj compiler.

During compilation through maven - I get only class file for java without weaving. .aj file is not compiled.

Please Help!!!!

the first aspect file - ExceptionAspects.aj

```
package com.aspectSample;

public aspect ExceptionAspects {

pointcut ExceptionHandler(Exception e) : handler(Exception+) && args(e) && within(com.clickable.*);
pointcut callbeforeMethod():execution( public void HelloWorldExclude.*(..)) ;

before(Exception ex) : ExceptionHandler(ex)
{       
    System.out.println("Added Aspects before Exception :"+ex.toString());
}

before(): callbeforeMethod()
{
    System.out.println("Aspect Before Method Call");
}


pointcut sysOutOrErrAccess() : get(* System.out) || get(* System.err);

declare error
  : sysOutOrErrAccess()
  : "Don't write to the console";

}
```

The source java file HelloWorldExclude.java
        package com.aspectSample;

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class HelloWorldExclude {

 private void FoulIntro(String message, String name) throws SQLException
    {
        throw new SQLException("WriteSomething");
    }

 public void GiveMeFoulIntro(String message, String name)
    {
        try
        {
            this.FoulIntro(message, name);

        }catch(SQLException exp)
        {
            System.out.println("catching exception");
        }
    }
}
```

and the pom.xml file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.clickable.HelloWorld-Maven</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorldAspect-Maven</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>HelloWorld Aspect</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>Hello World Code</description>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.11</org.aspectj-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                              <goal>compile</goal>                              
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration> 
                <source>${java-version}</source> 
                <target>${java-version}</target> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a stupid mistake in pom file. 
aspectj plugin was added under   element, which is just a configuration of all plugins. It doesn't tell compiler what to use.

It worked as soon as I removed plugin out of this element.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that you can try:

- Explicitly provide the dependencies of the maven-aspectj plugin:

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
          <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                  <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                  <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
              </dependency>
          </dependencies>
  ```

with the version of aspectjrt and aspectjtools matching the version of aspectj that you are using.

- Do you by any chance have any of your sources in the test folder,
  with the src/test folder, then to weave the aspects to the test sources you will have to explicitly mention that in the maven-aspectj plugin:

  ```
              <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>compile</goal>
                      <goal>test-compile</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
  ```